# Automated Testing tools for HTML5 Canvas

Tags: automated-tests, html5-canvas

I'm looking for a tool to do some automated GUI testing on a HTML5 canvas component we're developing. Basically I'm looking for a tool that is able to record the clicks and events on the canvas component and is able to replay those events.

So far most of the testing tools like Telerik WebUI Testing Suite, Selenium, TestSwarm, qUnit, Jasmine, Hudson seems that they don't fully support HTML5 canvas testing.

Would you guys know a testing tool that already supports that? If not, would you know how companies are doing automated testing of HTML5 canvas?

Answer (score 1):

In Telerik Test Studio latest release, we have added support for many of the HTML5 tags like Canvas, Audio and Video tags. All the HTML tags are accessible using code and are under the:

ArtOfTest.WebAii.HtmlControls namespace. You will find HTML5 controls like:

HtmlCanvas, HtmlAudio, HtmlVideo, HtmlMeter and all the expanded HtmlInput types like HtmlInputEmail, HtmlInputSearch..etc.

For the HtmlCanvas, you actually have access to the 2D Context of the control. So you even manipulate it and can do things like:

HtmlCanvas.Context2dRotate(), HtmlCanvas.Context2dTransform()...etc.